# How To 4 icons in right side of each row in list view

Tags: android

I want to set 3 icons to right side in each row of list view .I am making shopping app in which I want to when in list view user select any product so he/she could see product in  3 way like if user will select icon 1 so  user could see product in grid view and if user select   icon 2 so user can see product in image switcher,on icon 3 user can see products in list view actually  i wana user colud see products in 3 view.when click on icons so next activity open like if user select icon of grid view so next activity will open of grid view.this is my code

```
public class ListViewSupplementActivityActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setContentView(R.layout.listlayout);
ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
view.setAdapter(new CustomImageListAapter(this));

view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
if(position ==0)
{    
Intent ii = new Intent(ListViewSupplementActivityActivity.this,SingleListItem.class);

ii.putExtra("operation", position);
startActivity(ii);                                                           
}
if(position ==1){    
Intent in = new Intent(ListViewSupplementActivityActivity.this,Test.class);

in.putExtra("operation", position);
startActivity(in);
}
if(position == 5){
Intent in2= new               Intent(ListViewSupplementActivityActivity.this,FullImageActivity.class);       
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("operation", position);
in2.putExtras(bundle);   
startActivity(buse); }

}  


});
}
}
```

**This is custom adapter class**:

```
public class CustomImageListAapter extends BaseAdapter {

private int[] images = {R.drawable.autumnwalk, R.drawable.bridge,R.drawable.butterfly,               
R.drawable.cheetah, R.drawable.cloud, R.drawable.su, R.drawable.wi,
R.drawable.rocksculpture, R.drawable.skyatsunset, R.drawable.s,
R.drawable.smoke, R.drawable.tulips};

private String[] imageDesc = { "Autumn Walk", "Bridge",
"Butterfly", "Cheetah", "Cloud", "Highway", "Martini", 
"Rock Sculpture", "Sky at Sunset", "Sliced Orange", "Smoke",
"Tulips"};

private Context ctx = null;

public CustomImageListAapter(Context context) {
this.ctx = context;
}

public int getCount() {
return images.length;
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
}
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this.ctx);
imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
imgView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
imgView.setImageResource(images[arg0]);
imgView.setAdjustViewBounds(Boolean.TRUE);
imgView.setContentDescription(imageDesc[arg0]);
imgView.setMaxHeight(200);
imgView.setMaxWidth(200);

TextView tv = new TextView(this.ctx);
tv.setText(imageDesc[arg0]);
tv.setMaxHeight(100);
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


LinearLayout layoutView = new LinearLayout(this.ctx);
layoutView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
layoutView.addView(imgView, params1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
layoutView.addView(tv, params2);

return layoutView;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define and use a xml layout file for your list item row. The row will contain 4 **ImageViews** on the right side along with any other Views. And use this as the layout for each row. And based on the position in your `CustomAdapter` class you can get references to each of your rows.

Now, inflate this xml layout for list item row in `getView()` of **CustomAdapter**.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create custm view for your list viewor you can simply create a xml file for that and later in Adapter class inflate it.

like here i have create a xml file with two TextViews.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.two_text, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView

                .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

                holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView

                .findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }

            holder.text1.setText(CountriesList.abbreviations[position]);

            holder.text2.setText(CountriesList.countries[position]);

            return convertView;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To save time doing it programmatically, you can do as follow:

- **Create list_view_item xml** file (represent each view item). To do flexible alignment, you should use **`RelativeLayout`**.
- **Inflate** the above xml layout in your **array adapter**

(1) Create **`list_view_item.xml`** for item layout:

- The key work is set the first item to parent view's right: `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
- Then the following items are aligned by previous item: `android:layout_alignParentLeft="@+id/id_of_prev_item"`

**(EDITED for 3 images:)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="@+id/img1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="@+id/img2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="@+id/img3"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(2) Inflate item layout in `CustomImageListAapter`:

Suggestion: extend your `CustomImageListAapter` class from **`ArrayAdapter<T>`** to more specific use of data item and make your code more comprehensive.

```
public class CustomImageListAapter extend ArrayAdapter<YourDataItem>
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        int item_view_id = R.layout.list_view_item;

        LinearLayout holderView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflaterName = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflaterName );
        inflater.inflate(item_view_id, holderView, true);

        //YourDataItem: is your class represent each row on your database
        YourDataItem item = getItem(position);

        //TODO: do your stuff of works with your view item and data here

        return holderView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to extend CustomImageListAapter with ArrayAdapter?because i am not connecting it with database .i will make database letter on now i want to simple this task .i am getting error to extend it with ArrayAdapter

Comment: i did this in customImageListAdapter class

Comment: public View getView1(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup     parent)
    {
    int item_view_id = R.layout.listlayout;

    LinearLayout holderView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    String inflaterName = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)           getContext().getSystemService(inflaterName );
    inflater.inflate(item_view_id, holderView, true);

        
    

        

    return holderView;
    }

    private Context getContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;}

Comment: my xml file is listlayout in which i took list view and 3 images on right side.plzzzz help me

Comment: but icons r appearing just on 1 row.i wana it appear on all row and how to apply intent on each icon

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` is the best choice for your case, though not compulsory. what you mean by "how to apply intent on each icon"?, to open another activity by each list item on Clicked? See the answer in [open new intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276958/moving-between-activity/12277154#12277154)

Comment: You see the my Edited answer for 3 images