# Moving between Activity

Tags: android

I have 4 Activity. the first being the login activity and the 4th being the user sends the data to the server. Now what I want to do is when the data is sent successfully,i wan the user to move to activity 2 from activity 4. How can i acheive this scenario.

I need to implement this handleSuccessSaveOrder() which will take me from 4th to 2nd activity

```
private void saveOrder(final Order order) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                getConnection().saveOrder(order);
                //handleSuccessSaveOrder();
            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.d("--- ERROR ---", exc.getMessage());
                handleException(exc.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of your `handleSuccessSaveOrder()`, do as follow:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Your_activity_2_class_name.class);
intent.putExtra(PARAM_KEY, value); //use if you want to pass params to new intent
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Send the data
2. When the server has received all of the data, have it send a notification to the app saying so.
3. When your app receives the notification, use an intent to launch the Activity you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze the response of the server you (as the connection method you use). Once processed this answer, if correct, create a linked Intent to Activity 2 and run it with startActivity (Intent).